# How can HTML "link href" call same file from different folders?

Tags: php, html, directory

Here is my root folder :

```
index.php
stylesheets(folder) --->main.css
includes(folder)    --->header.php
folder1  (folder)           --->page1.php
```

Here is link part of "header.php" (from includes folder) :

```
<link href="stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Here is a part of index.php :

```
<?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
```

Here is a part of page1.php (from folder1):

```
<?php include "../includes/header.php"; ?>
```

Problem is, when I open index.php everything is normal.  As for /folder1/page1.php, it doesn't see styles but see content of header.php. That is to say, it doesn't bring main.css. Most probably, because of `link href="stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"` Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you access files from multiple levels, you should use an absolute path.

So either `href="http://domain.com/stylesheets/main.css"` or `href="/stylesheets/main.css"`

But this only works (the 2nd one, and the one I recommend) when you have it on top level on your domain.

Answer (score 3):

A robust solution is to use absolute links. A convenient way to do this is using a central configuration file. For instance, create a file `config.php`, containing

```
<?php

    define('SITE_ROOT', 'http://www.yourdomain.com/');

?>
```

And include this file in each PHP file (`require_once('config.php');`). Then you can write

```
<link href="<?php echo SITE_ROOT; ?>stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Which will always resolve to the URL you mean to reference. When your site's domain changes, a central configuration will allow you to easily change it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about your folder structure, but I understood correctly.

Try

```
href="../stylesheets/main.css"
```

Comment: When I try, /folder1/page1.php works normally but index.php doesn't see css styles.

Comment: file is included multiple levels. This again doesn't work on index.php. See my answer

Comment: This only shifts the error from one page to another; it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yeah use absolute paths shown above. That'll take like 5 minutes to implement, but it'll save problems down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simple way ist the best way: use an absolute path!