# HTML link to same file from different locations

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, navigationbar

I hold the html for a navigation bar for a website in a separate html file and include it with jQuery.  This has been working fine allowing me to update a single file to change the navigation on the whole site.  Now I have started using subfolders which is causing the navigation bar to break because I'm not always in the same directory as the navigation html.

At the moment I'm including the navigation bar like this:

```
$('#top_navbar').load("top_nav.txt");
```

and the navigation bar contains links to places like index.html.  I have started using the top_nav.txt file from subdirectories which means I need to call it like this:

```
$('#top_navbar').load("../top_nav.txt");
```

but the links inside it don't work because now they should point to ../index.html, for example.

An obvious solution is to use an absolute path, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420888/how-can-html-link-href-call-same-file-from-different-folders).  This makes development awkward though because the development page will go and get the live file (from www.example.com/index.html) rather than the development one (from C:\example\index.html).

I'm having this problem with much more than just the navigation bar too - CSS, JavaScript files etc.  What's the normal way of creating consistent navigation bars accross an entire site including pages in subfolders?

Comment: Basically you're trying to have a behavior similar to what iframes do, right?

Comment: Even more simple than that.  Here is the code that adds the navigation: `$('#top_navbar').load("top_nav.txt");`

Comment: I don't actually get what you mean by this. Do you want to reproduce the "../folder/path.html", and "./folder/path.html" thing? Or is it a completely different thing?

Comment: I have added a bit moree detail.  I just want the navigation bar to work if i'm in www.example.com and in www.example.com/subfolder